# How can I change the value of the button if I add it to a different ul?

Tags: button, html-lists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQtPA.png)

I'm using Vanilla JS. I do really want to change the value of my button from 'Add to Cart' to remove, if I add it to other ul. Creating a new li came up to my mind but I still have no idea how I would run the function. I tried creating an li dynamically, but then it's not running the function. I'm hoping that the value would change after I click the button, and I hope that it will add to the other ul.

Comment: Please share sample of your code so that it is easier to see your requirement.